# Unable to execute hello world on React native+ ios

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
return (
<Text>Hello World!</Text>
);
}

// App registration and rendering
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => App);
```

Above is the code I m trying to run but it fails giving following error on iOS simulator :

Application  has not been registered .This is due to require() error during initialisation or failure to call `AppRegistery.registerComponent`.

Please shed some light as to what is just happening.its my first encounter with `REACT` and this is not making me happy...

I guess it is the node version or the react version which is causing problems:

> Nodejs version : 4.4.5
>
> React native version : 0.28

Can someone just give me a proper guidance to start with react native.Official docs are just not helping :(

Comment: Is the name 'MyApp' correct?

Comment: go into AppDelegate.m and make sure the module name there is "MyApp"

Comment: Thankyou guys :) changing the app name worked...

Answer (score 0):

The name passed to the `AppRegistry.registerComponent` call has to match the name used in the `AppDelegate.m`:

```
...
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                  moduleName:@"YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE"
                                           initialProperties:nil
                                               launchOptions:launchOptions];
...
```

If you use one project with multiple applications there has to be at least one AppDelegate.m containing this module name